# Getting error "Geocoder failed due to: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I am using angular-google-map. When I click more than 3 time with few seconds getting error **Geocoder failed due to: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT**. How to avoid this type of error. I have brower google map key. but not included it, Is this one reason for getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this error appears when the limit is exceeded, see documentation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits

**UPDATE**

```
    .config(function(uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
 uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
  key: 'THIS-IS-WHERE-YOU-PASTE-THE-MAP-API-KEY-YOU-COPIED-EARLIER',
  v: '3.17',
  libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
 });
})
```

http://www.saintsatplay.com/blog/2015/03/using-google-maps-in-angular-js#.ViZBadLhCHs

Comment: I've updated the answer,

if I misunderstood the question, try to please more expand

Comment: I am following same approach, but on google developer console for gecoding api nothing get hit, I have enable to so that it can be use by any url, I am running on my local system, => localhost